# Oracle sql, update multiple rows using CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm trying to update multiple rows using CASE. The code below

```
UPDATE GRIDCOLUMNS  
SET TYPE= CASE  
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19337) THEN 6
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19339) THEN 6 
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19380) THEN 6
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19419) THEN 6
  END;
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
UPDATE GRIDCOLUMNS  
SET TYPE= CASE  
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19337) THEN 6
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19339) THEN 6 
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19380) THEN 6
  WHEN (Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID = 19419) THEN 6
  END
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("WEB"."GRIDCOLUMNS"."TYPE") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that a `CASE` expression with no `ELSE` clause evaluates to `null` if none of the search expressions are matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Instead:

```
UPDATE GRIDCOLUMNS  
    SET TYPE = 6
    WHERE Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID IN (19337, 19339, 19380, 19419);
```

This is much more efficient.  If you really need to use `CASE`, then you need an `ELSE`:

```
UPDATE GRIDCOLUMNS  
    SET TYPE = (CASE WHEN Fieldname = 'AccountNum' AND ID IN (19337, 19339, 19380, 19419) THEN 6
                     ELSE TYPE
                END);
```

Otherwise, the non-matching rows get set to `NULL`.  But really, use the `WHERE`.

Comment: or a where to limit to the ID's needed to update instead of all. (but case only really needed if you have different values to set)